# What would be the xml equivalent of the following java code for android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement this through xml instead but having too many failed attempts. I've tried creating two buttons and calling them by the ViewId but then they don't show up on the UI since they're custom buttons. How can I go about it?

```
 LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            recButton = new CustomRecordButton(this);
            ll.addView(recButton,
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0));
            playButton = new CustomPlayButton(this);
            ll.addView(playButton, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0));
            setContentView(ll);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<package.to.my.CustomPlayButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<package.to.my.CustomPlayButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So if my package is named package com.example.assignment22_audio_playback;
I would write <package com.example.assignment22_audio_playback.CustomPlayButton ?

Comment: I tried it but it keeps giving me class not found error when I view it through graphical, I also looked up similar examples but couldn't get it to work. The following classes could not be found:
- com.example.assignment22_audio_playback.CustomPlayButton (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class). that's what graphical display reads

Comment: try adding xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto btw it's not because you can't see it in the graphical editor that it does not work.